# jQuery keep selected content on load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a control panel, and I need to have the output of a command appear live. I have managed to get this to work by having the command output to a file, and loading that file via jQuery. I refresh the output every second using:

```
<script>
$(function(){
    setInterval(refreshFrame, 1000);
});
</script>
```

and

```
<script>
document.getElementById("title").innerHTML="Update";
function refreshFrame(){
     $("#frame").load("/assets/readfile.php?type=custom#content")
}
</script>
```

This works and loads the output without refreshing the entire page. However this makes copying impossible as the selection is gone or gets mutated as the contents are loaded again. Is there any way to keep the selection across reloads, and if not, how can I pause the refreshing when there is a selection?

Comment: Use AJAX instead of reloading...

Comment: I'm not reloading the page, just the div `frame`. Also, wouldn't ajax have the same problem of losing the selection upon refreshing the frame?

Comment: Umm... Yes. You are right...

Comment: You need to use event listeners for `click` or `touchmove` that clears the setInterval. Something like `$("#frame").on('click touchmove', function() {/* clear interval*/});`

Comment: You could also use jquery select() to select the text after a reload. But this only works on input or textarea elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this:

```
$(function(){
    document.getElementById("title").innerHTML="Update";
    setInterval(function(){
       if(!$('#frame').is(":hover")){
           $("#frame").load("/assets/readfile.php?type=custom#content")
        }      
  }, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about only updating the element's html if the content has changed and the user has not selected anything in #frame?

```
var lastContent;
$(function(){
    setInterval(refreshFrame, 1000);
});

function refreshFrame(){
     $.ajax({
          url:"/assets/readfile.php?type=custom#content"
     }).done(function(content) {
         if(!$(window.getSelection().anchorNode).is("#frame")  && $(window.getSelection().anchorNode).closest("#frame").length == 0 && content != lastContent) {
               $("#frame").html(content);
               lastContent=content;
         }

     });

}
```